# Can we add item to Android system listviews?

Tags: android

I want to write application that when one time executed add new Locale and Language to Android System.
I have researched, but have not found anything . So I decided done this task step by step.

First I interesting , can we add item to "Select Language" -> "Locale" system list view a item?

Answer (score 2):

> First I interesting , can we add item to "Select Language" -> "Locale"
>   system list view a item?

No, You cannot, unless you modify the platform and re-build android, and re-flash your device with the new binaries.

I can't quite parse the first part of your question to understand what you want to do. If you want to be notified when the locale changes ... For example, if you want to run some code when the user changes the locale, you can listen for this intent,

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED

Comment: Yes , you are right. I wrote messy.

I want to add Locale and Language list my country , which is not in Android System. And then I could select my language from this list (which above I said) and use it.

For example

Locale
English
Russian
My Language

Comment: And, if you have time, please give a little detailed information about "modify platform"

Thanks for all. 
Sorry for English

Comment: @Rufat: modify platform: source code of an android OS for a device. for example source Code of ICS 4.0 for Galaxy Note. you can modify it then compile it and get an MODIFIED version of ICS 4.0 platform. OK?

Comment: to add a language to the android system, you need to modify the android platformm as Rufat said. not to mention, ensure that all of the strings in the android platform are available for the new locale. a significant task indeed.

Comment: Thanks Maziar Bouali. 
just I do not say ok).
What do you think below link. Does it help me?
http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html